# Is there another Net Standard API like Regex to check if an URI matches with a template?

Tags: c#, .net-standard

Is there another api like Regex to check if an uri matches with a template?

```cs
public void Check()
{
 Check("http://domain/api/products/{productId}", "http://domain/api/products/2"); //return true
 Check("http://domain/api/something/{0}/otherThing/{1}", "http://domain/api/something/1/otherThing/2"); //return true 
 Check("http://domain/api/something/{p1}/otherThing/{p2}","http://domain/api/something/otherThing/1"); //return false
}

public bool Check(string uri, string template)
{
   return template.Match(uri); //method that I need...
}
```

Comment: yep.  it's literally called `UriTemplate` :)  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uritemplate?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: It seems that UriTemplate is not available in Net Standard... I did not specify it